# Emphasizing in paper: italic or bold?

Tags: publications, writing

I am preparing a paper for a conference in EECS field. *(Generic suggestions are also welcomed!)*

What should one do when they want to emphasize one particular word?
Should that word to be emphasized be in italic or bold?

I myself rarely see text in bold, which makes me wonder whether bold should only be used in section or subsection headings?

Comment: If you are lucky enough to use LaTeX, `\emph` all the way and let the conference template decide.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I am indeed using LaTeX, but do not know there is such a function! So it will automatically choose the style according to the template I am using? Wow!

Comment: Tried, seems that in my template, it is in italic. So I guess I will go with \emph. Thanks a lot! @FedericoPoloni

Comment: Yes, there is. Incidentally, if you learnt LaTeX from a source that still suggests the (old and deprecated) commands `\bf`, `\it` (or `$$...$$` for that matter), I urge you to look for something more modern.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  Indeed. Nice advice! :)

Comment: And another advanage: even if your style does not specify what "emph" is, you can easily change it all at once if you find out that some other type/font is required.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**It's a matter of style**: both bold and italic are typographically acceptable ways to emphasize part of your text, as are small caps, use of a different typeface or point size. (And, if you wonder: *no, [underlining is not considered good practice in modern printed text](http://practicaltypography.com/underlining.html)*).

However, **you are right that using bold is usually reserved for [headings or very strong emphasis](http://practicaltypography.com/bold-or-italic.html)** (think things like “Danger of electrocution — do not use under water” is an appliance user’s manual). The reason it is not commonly used inside [running text](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/running_text) is that it disrupts the overall level of gray of the page, drawing the eye from too far away: you want emphasis to make certain words stand out in the sentence, but you do not want the reader to skip directly to these words as soon as they set their eyes on the page.

There are, of course, always exceptions… like when you use bold (or color, or any other device that disrupt the grayness of the text), to emphasize a few stand-alone “take home messages” from a longer text, as I've done above!

Comment: Thanks for the http://practicaltypography.com/ link. I was looking for something like this.